# Display remote directory/all files in Jtree

Tags: file, sftp, jtree, jsch

i have some problem using JSCH to retrieve files/folders and populate them in JTree.
In JSCH to list files using :

Vector list = channelSftp.ls(path);

But i need that lists as java.io.File type. So i can get absolutePath and fileName, 
And i don't know how to retrieve as java.io.File type.

Here is my code, and i try it work for local directory.

```
public void renderTreeData(String directory, DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Boolean recursive) {
        File [] children = new File(directory).listFiles(); // list all the files in the directory
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // loop through each
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(children[i].getName());
            // only display the node if it isn't a folder, and if this is a recursive call
            if (children[i].isDirectory() && recursive) {
                parent.add(node); // add as a child node
                renderTreeData(children[i].getPath(), node, recursive); // call again for the subdirectory
            } else if (!children[i].isDirectory()){ // otherwise, if it isn't a directory
                parent.add(node); // add it as a node and do nothing else
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me, thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

you can define some variable in your java bean like

```
 Vector<String> listfiles=new Vector<String>(); // getters and setters

   Vector list = channelSftp.ls(path);
   setListFiles(list);  // This will list the files same as new File(dir).listFiles
```

in JSCH you can absolute path using [ChannelSftp#realpath](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/)  but unfortunately there no way to get Exact file with extension .But you can use something like this to check whether that file name existed in the target directory or not.

```
 SftpATTRS sftpATTRS = null;
  Boolean fileExists = true;
    try {
    sftpATTRS = channelSftp.lstat(path+"/"+"filename.*");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        fileExists = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (linux in remote server):

```
public static void cargarRTree(String remotePath, DefaultMutableTreeNode parent) throws SftpException { 
    //todo: change "/" por remote file.separator
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(remotePath); // List source directory structure.
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) { // Iterate objects in the list to get file/folder names.       
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(oListItem.getFilename());
        if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) { // If it is a file (not a directory).
            parent.add(node); // add as a child node
        } else{
            if (!".".equals(oListItem.getFilename()) && !"..".equals(oListItem.getFilename())) {
                parent.add(node); // add as a child node
                cargarRTree(remotePath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename(), node); // call again for the subdirectory
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you can invoque this method as:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode nroot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(sshremotedir);                
try {
    cargarRTree(sshremotedir, nroot);
} catch (SftpException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
yourJTree = new JTree(nroot);
```