# How can I list all the files from an SFTP server using Java?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm new to SFTP protocol. I need to list all the files and folders from a server using SFTP protocol. I implemented this using the JSch library:

```
public ArrayList<JSONObject> listFiles(String deviceName, String location) throws Exception
{

    this.sftpLogin();

    Vector fileListVector;
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
        fileListVector = channelSftp.ls("/");
    } else
    {
        fileListVector = channelSftp.ls("/"+location);
    }

    ArrayList<JSONObject> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object aFileListVector : fileListVector)
    {
        ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) aFileListVector;
        if (entry.getFilename().equalsIgnoreCase(".") || entry.getFilename().equalsIgnoreCase(".."))
        {
            continue;
        }
        SftpATTRS attrs = entry.getAttrs();

        fileList.add(ImportProtocolUtils.getFileJSONObject(attrs.isDir(), location, entry.getFilename()));
    }

    return fileList;
}
```

I tried 'shell' and 'exec' channel using this the protocol. But command 'ls' is not working.

Which is the best library for this in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recurse into the subdirectories.

Something like:

```
if (attrs.isDir())
{
    fileList.addAll(listFiles(deviceName, location + "/" + entry.getFilename());
}
```

See also [Display remote directory/all files in Jtree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15061852/850848).